# Record input from NAudio WaveIn, and save the output to Byte Array

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to be able to get input from a microphone device via NAudio.WaveIn, and then output that exact input to a byte array.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to create a `MemoryStream` and write recorded audio to it in the `DataAvailable` event of your `WaveIn` device. Once you're done, call `ToArray()` on the `MemoryStream`. Bear in mind that you will use a lot of memory if you record for more than a few seconds.